# Sum of Wiener, limit in probablitity

Tags: limits, probability-theory, brownian-motion, probability-limit-theorems

Show that the sequence is convergence in probability and set the limit of it:
$$\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n-1}\left(W_{(k+1)/n}^2-W_{k/n}^2-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(W_{(k+1)/n}-W_{k/n}\right).$$

If there wasn't square it would be very similar to definition of integral with respect to Wiener process. But it isn't. Please help me :(

Susan ;*

Comment: I have similar problem